# Twitter API to fetch Tweets in Python

Tags: python, api, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I'm trying to fetch Tweets from multiple Twitter accounts and then create a database with the TWEETS and the source of the TWEET " user name " by using the following code

```
posts = api.user_timeline(screen_name = 'AlArabiya_Brk', count = 100 , lang = 
"ar",tweet_mode="extended")
df = pd.DataFrame([tweet.full_text for tweet in posts], columns = [ 'Tweets'])
```

but I have a question: how can I add more than one account? I tried doing:

```
posts = api.user_timeline(screen_name = ['AlArabiya_Brk','AJABreaking'], count = 100 
,lang ="ar",tweet_mode="extended")
```

but didn't get the desired output

Comment: Maybe try: `[status.screen_name for status in posts]`, but just a guess tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make multiple calls with that method.

That API endpoint only allows a single screen name input.